# How to create R markdown with empty code chunk?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

How can I add an empty code chunk in R markdown? I have found several options to manipulate the html to give more white space. But I would like to present some empty lines in the well known gray code box in order to indicate space for assigments.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
output: html_document
---

## R Markdown

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Homework 

Please calculate the mean of the `speed` variable in `cars`.

```{r}



```
````

Comment: Would something like `# Insert code here` do?

Comment: If I add a line of comment in the R chunk, it still does not show any more empty lines. I could start each line with a #, but that seems to me like a strange workaround.

Comment: I think some sort of workaround is necessary, because fundamentally knitr treats code chunks as code, not preformatted text as you're asking it to. I've added an answer with some options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hacky way... almost there:

````
```{r, code="'\n\n\n\n'", results=F}
```
````

[image]

A possible solution using `results = 'asis'` and relying on chunck HTML class:

````
```{r,  results='asis', echo=F}
cat(
  '<pre class="r">
  <code class = "hlsj"> <span class="hljs-string"> <br> <br> </span> </code>
  </pre>
  ')
```
````

[image]

Just add `<br>` to increase the number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a way to get knitr to recognise a completely empty chunk as a chunk. It will always omit it, regardless of the chunk options.

You have to insert something to get it to render, for example a comment. So you can put the empty lines between two comments:

````
---
output: html_document
---

## Homework 

Please calculate the mean of the `speed` variable in `cars`.

```{r}
# Insert code here



# End
```
````

[image: Result of chunk 1]

Or with the `strip.white=FALSE` chunk option we can use a single comment line, but strangely this only works for leading, not trailing, whitespace:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(strip.white = FALSE)
```

## Homework 

Please calculate the mean of the `speed` variable in `cars`.

```{r}



# Insert code above
```
````

[image: Result of chunk 2]